# How to Enable 'Kill Application' button in Yarn web UI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to add Kill button

[image: link to image]

I tried :

- Login to Ambari Web site and go to YARN Configs page
- Search yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.ui-actions.enabled
- If it exists, change the value to true
- If it does not exist, clear the filter and add it from 'Custom yarn- -   site' then 'Add Property...' and set the value to true.
- Save and restart required components

based on Apache Ambari Version 2.6.1.5